# xargs how I can specify replace the {} with N inputs?

Tags: xargs

I would like to do something like following

```
find ./testsrc -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 -n10 -I{} cp --parents {} <dest>/
```

The cp is just an example of command that expect something after the input got from xargs. I know in this case I might do `| xargs -0 -P4 -n10 cp --parents -t <dest>/` but there are commands cannot do this.

Here `-n` conflicts with `-I`

How can I achieve same effect with `-I{}`?

Comment: If you have GNU cp, you can use `xargs -0 cp --parents -t "$dest" --` to avoid needing a sigil to specify a non-final position in the first place; the `-t` argument lets the target/destination be put in a non-terminal position on the command line. For the more general case, I do what jjo's answer suggests, using `sh -c` with `"$@"` in an appropriate position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using Linux's `xargs` which gives the below warning (`--max-args` is the same as  `-n`) :

```bash
xargs: warning: options --max-args and --replace/-I/-i are mutually exclusive, ignoring previous --max-args value
```

As indeed `-I` will only consume a single element from the input, to keep `-n10` you'll need a different approach. Below command line works by ab-using shell's `${@}`, letting `-n10` pass all these args to a `sh` which wraps the `cp` run:

```bash
find ./testsrc -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P4 -n10 sh -c 'cp --parents "$@" <dest>/' --
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: wow, this save my week. The key is `--` I actually tried similar thing by myself. But when there is no `--` at the end, the `$@` is missing first argument.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` cannot do this directly. GNU Parallel, however, can:

```
find ./testsrc -type f -print0 |
  parallel -0 -P4 -n10 -I{} cp --parents {} <dest>/
```

(`-I{}` is redundant, `-P4` is the default if you have 4 CPU threads).